# Не передается пропс (не реактивен?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет
В родительском компоненте по нажатию кнопки идет загрузка архива на бэк .

в ответ бэк присылает накоторые данные

```
const dataList = ref([]}

const dataList = await ApiModule.api.infoExhangeService.uploadArchive(formData)
```

эти данные я обратываю и передаю как пропс в дочерний  компоненет

```
    <edit-archive
        :dataList="dataList"
      ></edit-archive>
```

В дочернем компоненте я принимаю пропс:

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
dataList: Array
  },
      setup (props: any) {
    console.log('props', props.dataList)
```

и вот тут начинаются непонятные штуки.
если в лог написать просто props, что можно развернуть пропрс, Target и найти в нем dataList
если же наисать props.dataList. То Данных нет - undefined

Также данные на появляются в дочернем компоненте сразу.
Вот я загрузил архив, вижу эти данные в родителе,  а в дочернем компоненте, в таблице где должны быть эти данные они появлются если в студии выполнить сохранение. Т.е. сразу данных почему-то нет.

Answer (score 0):

При передаче входных параметров нужно использовать kebab-case:

```
<edit-archive
        :data-list="dataList"
      ></edit-archive>
```

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html